# How to style file tag of html?

Tags: html, css

I want to give file tag in my form to be consistent with rest of the tag. So I want to give it a proper styling. But by searching a lot on internet I found it is difficult to achieve. I found many answer but nothing is working. I want that the button which shows `"Choose File"` can be style in the same way with rest of the buttons. But no luck.  Or what I want is that I will provide a text-box and a button over file tag. Clicking on button will internally result in clicking on file tag. But I don't know how to get the name of file selected using file tag so that I displayed it in the text box. I am using Linux. There are some solutions which give this functionality but give name something like this `"C://fakepath/name"`.I don't want this. I  only want name of file not path.Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: you cannot, you can use javascript to fake it. hide it and use other elements wich will retrieve value and send action to input file.

Comment: ok thanks i will try to do something.

Comment: @SumitRathore Try wrapping a label tag around the file tag. http://jsfiddle.net/cxgAJ/ (in the jsfiddle, click the red box)

Comment: @DennisMartinez thanks a lot but Alpha's solution is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using shadow dom selectors

```
/*styles the button*/
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button{background-color:red; color:white; }
/*styles the file name*/
input[type="file"]{color:red; }
```

Not sure how it will work on Linux but it displays fileName.extension on OS X.